# Stop tailing a file on remote server when the input stops Using paramiko and Flask

Tags: python, linux, flask, paramiko

I looked around for a while and haven't found an answer to this.

Here is my use case:

I have several processes on a remote that is executed via a python script using paramiko to ssh to the machine. My issue at this point is that the first script executes fine but hangs due to the tail action from paramiko does not exit. Below is the current relevant code.

**Making the ssh connection:**

```
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction


def get_logs(appid, app):
    try:
        ssh = client.connect_ssh(IPADDRESS, USER)
        interact = SSHClientInteraction(ssh, timeout=10, display=False)
        interact.send('tail -f <Path to file>)
        interact.tail(line_prefix=str(app)+': ')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Ctrl+C interruption detected, stopping tail')
    finally:
        ssh.close()
```

*There is a helper function not shown but this is not where the issue lies so I didn't include it.*

**The relevant portion of the main app code**

```
@app.route('/processing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def processing():
    form = InstitutionForm()
    version_selected = form.versions.data
    resp = make_response(render_template('processing.html', form=form))
    sp_id = (request.cookies.get('sp_id').strip("[]").replace("L", ""), "SP")
    rs_appid = (request.cookies.get('rs_base_id').strip("[]").replace("L", ""), "RS Base")
    print "Undeploying"
    for i in [rs_appid, sp_id]:
        print i[0]
        app_actions.undeploy(i[0].strip())
        app_actions.get_logs(i[0].strip(), i[1])
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
            status = app_actions.check_status(i, "'undeploy'")[0][2]
            print status
            if status == 'failure':
                print "undeploy failed"
                break
            elif status == 'success':
                print "undeploy succeded"
                break
            else:
                print "processing"
                pass
```

So my issue is that as the script goes through the `processing()` function it starts displaying the logs as desired from the `app_actions.get_logs()` call. After that it hangs. This seems to be because the tail call in the `get_logs()` function doesn't end.

My question summed up is:

Using paramiko how can I tail a file until it stops then exit and close the ssh connection so the next part of the loop can run?

I'm sorry if there are any errors or mistakes or omissions from this question, it is my first question asked on **SO**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement this using pure Python as opposed to using `tail`. This was part of Dan Beazy's talk on generators.

```
import time

def tail(fin):
    fin.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = fin.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

_fin = open("path/to/file","r")
lines = tail(_fin)
for line in lines:
    print line,
```

Comment: Thats a great idea @eagle! Where I'm not sure is how to read the file from the remote machine using a solution like this. I will play with it some more trying this route. I guess instead of using just `open` I could establish the ssh connection and read the file that way. Thanks for the response!

Comment: you can make this a standalone script with a main function and have your command send to your instance be to execute this script on your file, does that make sense?

Comment: Yep it does. Just edited my comment before I saw this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer given by [eagle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8746930/eagle) was correct and pointed me in the right direction, after some research I found a better solution. This solution is specifically for the `paramiko_expect` library that I am using. There are a couple of functions you can call to break out of the `tail` loop.

[Here](https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect/pull/24/files) is the pull request in which they were added.

Personally I used the `timeout` function to wait for 15 seconds after no input received to break out of the loop. This works perfectly for me.

**Here is the revised code:**

```
def get_logs(appid, app):
    try:
        ssh = client.connect_ssh(IPADDRESS, USER)
        interact = SSHClientInteraction(ssh, timeout=10, display=False)
        interact.send('tail -f <path to file>')
        interact.tail(line_prefix=str(app) + ': ', timeout=15)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Ctrl+C interruption detected, stopping tail')
    except Exception:
        ssh.close()
    finally:
        try:
            ssh.close()
        except:
            pass
```

Also wanted to throw out a big thanks to [fotis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1905666/fotis-gimian) for writing a fantastic module that is allowing me to do great automations.